# How to update particular folder/file from central repository in Git?

Tags: git, repository

Is there a way to update folder or file alone in Git? I had cloned from central repository and wish to update only specific folder/files.

Answer (score 12):

you can use `git fetch` to update the objects in your local clone, and then you can `git checkout` those particular files.

For example - if your remote is called origin and you only want to update `main.c` from the master branch you can do this:

```
git checkout origin/master main.c
```

This will update the file in your working directory and add it to the index ready to be committed on your local branch.

Comment: How about for folders? @Abizern

Answer (score -3):

No, you can only fetch/pull commits, which will affect the entire repository.

Comment: That may be true for `pull`, but you can `fetch` from the remote instead and what you choose to bring into your local branch and working directory is up to you.