# Git checkout only new files from branch directory

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have such situation.
One developer is working in ./model directory and he is adding new files to it then he commit the new model_files and push to origin/master

Now second developer is writing models too in the same directory ./model (in his own working directory).

Suppose developer A create such models:

```
./model/m1.php
./model/m2.php
```

Now the developer B create such models:

```
./model/m3.php
./model/m4.php
```

Suppose developer A commit changes and push to the origin/master because developer B need m1.php and m2.php models to his work.

The developer B also created many other changes/folders/files in project not only in ./models directory and his work is not finished yet. If he merge or pull then his work will lost.

How can the developer B retrieve the new model files in folder ./model only that developer A created.
I tried something like this on developer B machine. I assume that developer B didn't commit m3.php and m4.php because didn't end with that files yet. He just need to have in ./models directory new files (m1.php and m2.php) from developer A. On developer B machine i tried:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/master ./model/*
```

But unfortunately the error gives me

```
error: pathspec 'model/m3.php' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'model/m4.php' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

But if I execute:

```
git checkout origin/master ./model/m1.php ./model/m2.php
```

Then it works but this assumes that I have to know exacly file names that I need to checkout from this branch.

Can somebody help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: [single file git][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138817/how-to-update-particular-folder-file-from-central-repository-in-git

Comment: It works but I have to know exacly the new file names.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why aren't you using branches for this? Have dev A working on his own m1m2 branch, then dev B can set up a tracking branch on his end and pull m1m2 and merge into his own branch m3m4?

Comment: We are just learning git and our confidence about branching is very low right now.

Answer (score 3):

Developer B should run

> 1. git stash
> 2. git pull origin master
> 3. git stash apply

Line 1 stashes the developers work so their branch is free of changes before performing the pull

Line 2 performs a fetch and merge from the master directory on the remote.  This will get Developer A's changes.

Line 3 reapplies Developer B's work on the m3.php and m4.php files.

Obviously, do not include the numbers when executing the commands in git.

Comment: git pull will give me conflicts from other project directories and now we didn't plan to merge some folders. We only want to pull from this one directory ./model

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. Almost everything was ok except this '*' at the end.

The proper way to download files from remote branch to some project folder only adding new files to this folder:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/master model/
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge incoming changes into your working copy. In order to do so, just:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

In order to do so, you must first either commit or stage local changes in computer B.

Comment: But merge will be working on all project directories and we want only on ./model directory. If developer B merge all project directories then will be disaster in our case.

Answer (score 1):

Your shell expands

git checkout origin/master ./model/*

before git sees it. It is probably expanding to

```
git checkout origin/master ./model/m1.php ./model/m2.php ./model/m3.php ./model/m4.php
```

and then you get the error from git that `master` is missing `model/m3.php` and `model/m3.php`. Telling the shell to not expand your `*`, like

```
git checkout origin/master './model/*'
```

seems to work, or just use the explicit path as per other solutions, like

```
git checkout origin/master model/
```